# Error: Stray end tag

Tags: html

Что нужно исправить в данном коде чтобы он стал валидным и бузе ошибок?

```html
<h2><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </i></i> текст </h2> <h2><i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> </i></i> текст </h2>
```

Comment: убрать `</i></i>`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в каждом теге `<h2>` присутствуют лишние закрывающие теги `</i></i>`, отсюда и ошибка при проверке валидатором. Чтобы не было ошибки необходимо переписать таким образом:

```
<h2><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> текст </h2> 
<h2><i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> текст </h2>
```

Comment: Чтобы ответ был более полезным, хорошо бы рассказать в чем была проблема и что изменилось.

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на недостаток. Дополнил ответ.